# JPanel inside a JPanel inside a JTabbedPane doesn't show up

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtabbedpane

I have a JPanel (firstPanel) which is embedded into an other JPanel (secondPanel). I want to create a JTabbedPane with two tabs: one for the firstPanel and one for the secondPanel.
However, when I switch to secondPanel, the embedded firstPanel won't show up.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;


public class Application extends JFrame
{   
    public Application()
    {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 300));


        JPanel firstPanel = new JPanel();
        firstPanel.add(new JLabel("first"));

        JPanel secondPanel = new JPanel();

//      JPanel thirdPanel = new JPanel();
//      thirdPanel.add(new JLabel("third"));
//
//      secondPanel.add(thirdPanel);
        secondPanel.add(firstPanel);
        secondPanel.add(new JLabel("second"));

        JTabbedPane mainPanel = new JTabbedPane();
        mainPanel.addTab("First", firstPanel);
        mainPanel.addTab("Second", secondPanel);

        this.add(mainPanel);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Application app = new Application();
        app.pack();
        app.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

When I add the thirdPanel instead of the first, it works as expected.
Am I missing something obvious? 
Thanks you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because you are trying to add a single panel to two different parents, one being your `secondPanel`, and the other being your tab.  You can't do that.

Can I ask why you think you want to do this?  There is probably a better solution out there for you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm developing a game, where I have a characterPanel to show and modify the attributes of the user's character. This would be my first tab. And I have an Arena where that character could battle with computer generated ones. And that would be my second tab. However I want to show the user's character and the enemy character next to each other. And I thought the simplest solution would be just embed the characterPanel.

Comment: Sounds to me like you could get away with subclassing `JPanel` then and creating two instances of that.